# Determining the branch of logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I want to determine a branch of logarithm such that $f(z)=L(z^3-2)$ is analytic at $0$. I am not really sure how to find a branch but I will explain few things I tried.

Since $z^3-2$ maps $0$ onto $-2$, what needs to be done is to find a branch of logarithm which is analytic at $-2$.So if L is a branch of logarithm, by the chain rule we have that $L(z^3-2)$ is analytic at $0$ since $z^3-2$ is analytic at $0$. I just don't know how to proceed from here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you cut along the positive reals, you obviously avoid $-2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't think I understood what you said

Answer (score 1):

You can define a logarithm on any simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, so this can for instance be $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}^+$.

This logarithm $L$ is a holomorphic function, so composing it with the holomorphic $z \mapsto z^3-2$ gives a holomorphic function $f$. Holomorphic functions are analytic on their domain, so $f$ will be analytic at $0$ as well as at any point on which it is defined.

Comment: So $L(z^3-2)$ is the answer?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? If $L$ is *a* logarithm (you can construct many, there is no canonical one) then $L(z^3-2)$ is automatically analytic at $0$ *if it is defined*.

Comment: I meant the purpose was to determine a branch of logarithm. Hence I showed that $L(z^3-2)$ is analytic at 0 my answer is correct then?

Comment: I am sorry I have not still understood properly what a branch of logarithm exactly is so I thought I have to find some explicit function for $f(z)$

Comment: @Chocosup You said L is a holomorphic function. On what domain are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(z)=z^3-2$. The chain rule asserts that $f$ will be differentiable at each point $z$ for which $g(z)$ lies in the domain consisting of all points of the complex plane except those lying on the nonpositive real axis (the branch cut of Log ($z$)). Thus, $f$ will not be analytic at the points where $z^3-2$ is negative or zero if $L$ is the principal value of the logarithm. At the point zero, $g(z)=-2$, which is a negative real number. This means we must use a branch of the logarithm that has its branch cut not along the negative reals.

We can specify the logarithm branch $L(z)=\mbox{Log }|z|+i\arg_0(z)$ where $\arg_0(z)$ is the branch of arg(z) in the interval ($0$, $2\pi$), which solves the problem.